# Can we add text to the effect that ORA-00600 errors are off-topic?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

(IMHO) Oracle ORA-00600 errors should be considered off-topic here because they're internal errors and there's very little we can do to diagnose and help people with them. The recommended and best way to get them resolved is to raise a support request with Oracle.

Assuming the consensus is that ORA-00600 questions *are* off-topic:

- Can we add text to the effect that ORA-00600 errors are off-topic and that the asker should contact Oracle support?

  More generically, the text could be added to the bullet list under **dba.se is *not* the right place to ask questions about...**, something like:

  - DBMS internal errors. In particular, if you have an ORA-00600 error, contact Oracle support.
- Can we even check for ORA-00600 when asking a question and warn about these being off-topic?

Answer (score 10):

We could instead create a canonical question (or reuse an existing one as canonical) and close other questions as its duplicates. Perhaps [this recent answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/225375/6965) could serve as a starting point for – if not actually *be* – the canonical one:

> The wording on this error might as well be:
>
> > ORA-00600: "Something" is broken in the database.
>
> It "recently" gained a close "cousin":
>
> > ORA-07445: "Something" is broken, but not necessarily in the database itself.
>
> If there's nothing immediately obvious in the logs, raise a Support call with Oracle.

Comment: @BalazaPapp has a good overview on how to try to resolve ORA-00600 errors. In the past; I always tried to focus my efforts on finding workarounds.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: The timing was good. If he'd posted his answer three minutes earlier, I wouldn't have bothered with mine :) I'll let it stay for the time being. I'm actually unsure if his stance actually disagrees with yours or not.

Comment: this is the proper way to handle such issues.  find a canonical answer and close everything else as dupes.  you don't want to end up with a long, windy list of "what's on and off topic".

Comment: I think this is the right approach, and Balazs' answer would be an even better canonical answer than the one you link.

Answer (score 10):

ORA-00600 errors can be solved as:

1. Go to https://support.oracle.com. Search for the error using the ORA-00600 lookup tool (the first argument between `[...]`), or a generic search as ORA-00600 + first argument, look at the list of notes and bugs related to your case.
2. If you found a relevant bug/note, apply the patch or workaround.
3. If you found a relevant bug/note, but there is no patch or workaround for your version, request that patch from Oracle by opening a service request asking for that, and the patch might be released in a few weeks.
4. (Optional, but what I prefer to do) If you found nothing relevant: try working it out on your own, Google the first argument for blogs, forums, mailing lists, inspect the call stack, search for similar errors based on that, experiment with alternatives to what caused the error, etc.
5. As the very last resort, if you have the patience of a saint, open a service request with Oracle. You might get a solution in a few months.

Most of the people posting here can not get past through even step 1, because the content on that site can be accessed only with a valid Oracle support contract, which they don't have.
Usually I do this for questions posted here and find some notes/bugs, but:

- It is not allowed to reveal unpublished content on a public forum.
- I just can't be bothered to start detailed investigation in comments, knowing that I may not even receive any further answer for asking just the database version or a few lines from the log/trace.

So unless it is a trivial case, the question will be just abandoned or closed as off-topic, too broad, whatever.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. :) The opening of your answer leads me to think that you disagree with Colin's opinion that these questions are unanswerable. But the conclusion kind of suggests the opposite (that you agree with him). What's your opinion actually?

Comment: @AndriyM I agree with him. Yes, such questions can be answered, but they are out of scope of this site.

Comment: I see now, thanks!